# TLS failed in Docker

Tags: ssl, docker, https

I have very limited knowledge about TLS certification. I wanted to enable https for docker daemon. I followed [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) tutorial but at the end failed to start docker daemon.

I am using docker in a Ubuntu 16.04 VM and my client and server is the same machine. So I use the `$hostname` as the '`Common Name`' during all the process.

After following the whole process in docker documentation when I run

```
sudo dockerd --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem -H=0.0.0.0:2376
```

I get the INFO log that "`API listen on [::]:2376`"

When I use the below command:

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem -H=$HOST:2376 version
```

I get proper response.

But when I reload the daemon and try to start docker it says failed to start docker and give the following message-

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.  
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of 'journalctl -xe' is:
[image]

I copied the necessary certificate to `~/.docker/` and the '`ExecStart`' in my `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file is:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H 0.0.0.0:2376 \
     --tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/sakib/.docker/ca.pem \
     --tlskey=/home/sakib/.docker/key.pem \
     --tlscert=/home/sakib/.docker/cert.pem
```

When I try to communicate with the API I get the following response:

```
$ curl -X GET https://0.0.0.0:2376/images/json

curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Certificate is bad

$ docker version

Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 05:33:38 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://EL802:2376/v1.24/version: x509: certificate is valid for $HOST, not EL802
```

NOTE: EL802 is my hostname which I set as the 'HOST' environment variable.

I think the problem is with the 'CN' name that I chose while creating client certificate. I create the server and client certificate as below-

Server:

```
openssl req -subj "/CN=$HOST" -sha256 -new -key server-key.pem -out server.csr
```

Client:

```
openssl req -subj '/CN=$HOST' -new -key key.pem -out client.csr
```

As my client and server is my host machine(EL802) which I set as the `$HOST` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picture does not show the full error line, but if the error message is:

```
 pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

Try and delete the pid, and restart.
Also double-check your [docker installation on Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/), and its [systemd configuration](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options).

> x509: certificate is valid for $HOST, not EL802

That means the certificate has been created with the string $HOST instead of its actual value.

```
openssl req -subj '/CN=$HOST'
```

The strong quoting of the single quotes would prevent the shell to replace `$HOST` with its value. Use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the pid issue. That was a mistake while taking the picture. I have edited the problem. My main problem is actually the CN name that I chose while creating the CSR for server/client. But I do not know what should be the FQDN name(e.g CN name) for the server/client when I am using a simple VM which does not belong to any domain(ex- X.X.com)

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it gives a new error. Not sure I should create a new issue for this. Now if I try to connect with the API I get the following warning which is pretty strange.

$ curl https://$HOST:2376/images/json \

>   --cert ~/.docker/cert.pem \

>   --key ~/.docker/key.pem \

>   --cacert ~/.docker/ca.pem

curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (EL802) does not match target host name 'EL802'

Comment: @zamansakib yes, closing this one (accepting) and making a new question with a link back to this one would be easier to manage.